# How do I view the Load Test Analyzer in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing, load, analyzer

I'm running my first load test, but I can't see the Load Test Analyzer.

Been through the toolbars, view menu, etc.. I find plenty of documentation of what it is and what it does, but nothing on how to view the darned thing!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Apparently after the first test is completed the analyzer/monitor pops up all by itself.

Just wouldn't do it on the first run. Weird.

Comment: But I wonder, why must I wait two days to select this as the appropriate answer? I know it is correct because I've tested it. Waiting 2 days will not make it any more, or less, correct or incorrect. 2 + 2 will equal 4 today, tomorrow, and the day after. No need to wait until Friday to know that!